# My Tabs are Missing in Kate

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kate

Normally, the Kate text editor allows me to open multiple documents at the same time into a tab interface. Now, though, I have no tabs and I don't see in the menu how to get them back. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find turn off/on tabs option here: *Settings* -> *Show tabs*. Like on screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help the blind!